# Vertical Scrolling inside a GridView / AdaptiveGridView

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to add vertical scrolling to my GridView / AdaptiveGridView, but no success so far(Horizontal scrolling works).

I have already attempted with internal scrollviewer with the "ScrollViewer.---" in the GridView without luck.

I have also tried to place a ScrollViewer outside of the GridView without luck.

XAML

```
<ScrollViewer
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
    <Grid Name="ChangeMe">
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView
            Name="MyPolls"
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            DesiredWidth="320"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="MyPolls_ItemClick"
            ItemHeight="180"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind oc}"
            SizeChanged="MyPolls_SizeChanged">
            <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Poll">
                    <Grid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
                        <Image Source="../Assets/Square44x44Logo.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        <StackPanel
                            Height="60"
                            Padding="12"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Background="{ThemeResource SystemBaseLowColor}"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind poll_title}" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}"
                                    Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding poll_description}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code Behind

```
private void MyPolls_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeMe.Height = MyPolls.Height;
            ChangeMe.Width = MyPolls.Width;
        }
```

Does anyone know a way to enable vertical scrolling for a GridView / AdaptiveGridView for when the gridview items go out of frame so you can scroll down and see them? (AdaptiveGridView inherits from GridView)

Comment: Maybe try to limit the size of the Grid with MaxHeight/MaxWidth. Or if it is part of another Grid/stackPanel or whatever then make those limitations in there. See if that works.

Comment: You mean the grid inside of the scrollviewer? If so how would i got about getting the max width / height possible within the current frame?

Comment: Just try it out before thinking about that. Try to set those two properties on the grid.

Comment: did you try setting the `VertivalScrollMode` to auto, `HorizontalScrollMode` to disabled?

Comment: @AlexanderBruun What's your parent of your GridView? I don't think you need to add ScrollViewer out of your AdaptiveGridView. Maybe there are some other settings which affect your result.